# STM32 rotate motor using TIM2

Tags: c, stm32

I have code that rotate motor it's working well:

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"
#include "stm32f10x_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f10x_rcc.h"

void Delay(unsigned int t) {
   unsigned int i;
   for (i = 0; i < t; i++)
      ;
}
void GPIOD_Initialize() {
   GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIOA_Stepper;
   RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
   GPIOA_Stepper.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0 | GPIO_Pin_1 | GPIO_Pin_2 | GPIO_Pin_3;
   GPIOA_Stepper.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
   GPIOA_Stepper.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
   GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIOA_Stepper);
}
void RotateToRight() {
   const int time = 25000;
   uint16_t commands[8] = { GPIO_Pin_0 | GPIO_Pin_2, GPIO_Pin_0, GPIO_Pin_3
         | GPIO_Pin_0, GPIO_Pin_3, GPIO_Pin_1 | GPIO_Pin_3, GPIO_Pin_1,
         GPIO_Pin_2 | GPIO_Pin_1, GPIO_Pin_2 };
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      GPIO_Write(GPIOA, commands[i]);
      Delay(time);
   }
}
int main(void) {
   GPIOD_Initialize();
   while (1) {
      RotateToRight();
   }
}
```

Then i decided to rewrite this code using timer TIM2. I think that i something done wrong because motor does not rotates but only beeps. Problem with pwm signal in second code. But I do not have an oscilloscope to check the physical characteristics of the signal on the legs. How to fix second code?

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"
#include "stm32f10x_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f10x_rcc.h"

void Delay(unsigned int t) {
   unsigned int i;
   for (i = 0; i < t; i++)
      ;
}
int main(void) {
   RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);

   RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM2, ENABLE);

   GPIO_InitTypeDef PORT;

   PORT.GPIO_Pin = (GPIO_Pin_0 | GPIO_Pin_1 | GPIO_Pin_2 | GPIO_Pin_3);

   PORT.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;
   PORT.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
   GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &PORT);

   TIM2->CCER |=
         (TIM_CCER_CC1E | TIM_CCER_CC2E | TIM_CCER_CC3E | TIM_CCER_CC4E);

   TIM2->CCMR1 |= (TIM_CCMR1_OC2M_0 | TIM_CCMR1_OC2M_1 | TIM_CCMR1_OC2M_2);
   TIM2->CCMR2 |= (TIM_CCMR2_OC3M_0 | TIM_CCMR2_OC3M_1 | TIM_CCMR2_OC3M_2
         | TIM_CCMR2_OC4M_0 | TIM_CCMR2_OC4M_1 | TIM_CCMR2_OC4M_2);
   TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;
   while (1) {
      int value = 10;
      int time = 25000;
      TIM2->CCR1 = value;
      TIM2->CCR3 = value;
      Delay(time);
      TIM2->CCR1 = value;
      Delay(time);
      TIM2->CCR4 = value;
      TIM2->CCR1 = value;
      Delay(time);
      TIM2->CCR4 = value;
      Delay(time);
      TIM2->CCR2 = value;
      TIM2->CCR4 = value;
      Delay(time);
      TIM2->CCR2 = value;
      Delay(time);
      TIM2->CCR3 = value;
      TIM2->CCR2 = value;
      Delay(time);
      TIM2->CCR3 = value;
      Delay(time);
   }
}
```

Comment: You can't write delay loops like that, the compiler will optimize them away. You will have to declare the loop iterator as volatile. But there's no reason you should use such loops anyhow, use hardware timers instead.

Comment: @Lundin,it's about second example?

Comment: The delay loop is incorrectly written in both examples.

Comment: @Lundin, maybe it is incorrectly but without them first example does not work.

Comment: Enable compiler optimizations and there's a big chance your program will break as well.

Comment: You have to enable timer output of the pin. You set the alternate function *mode* with this line `PORT.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;` but it's not enough. You should also set *which alternate function* you need. After a google search I found this function `GPIO_PinAFConfig`. If you do a search you will find some example use.